# How can I find exact error at perticular line in android logcat?

Tags: android

In java when there comes any exception, it gives me the error at line number,
but android logcat is very confusing, how to know exact error line?

How to find exact error line number, where I am doing wrong, or where any exception is concurring?
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: there is a caused by part look and indicates the line also

Comment: 04-29 11:41:26.947: W/System.err(3508):  at com.xxx.xxxxxx.image.xxxxClass.access$0(xxxxclass.java:59). here 1sy is your package name with java class and in() class name with line number

Comment: Logcat  shows activity package name with "Cause by" part with specified line number. when you click on that error line in logcat ,  Your error will be visible in class.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the line of logcat with your package name it'll redirect you to that line of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat also gives you the error and line number. It prints the exact same stack trace that you would see in any other java program. There is no difference, you just need to find your stack trace among the other messages being printed to Logcat by other apps. You can use filters for that:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#logcat